# flutter: CupertinoAlertDialog looks different from what is shown in official docs

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried implementing the CupertinoAlertDialog (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoAlertDialog-class.html) but when I used it, it looked like this:

[image]

which is quite different from how it looks when signing in with google or as shown in the image here (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/cupertino)

[image]

Here's the code:

```
showDialog(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: true,
          builder: (_) => _buildAlertDialog());

Widget _buildAlertDialog() {
    return CupertinoAlertDialog(
      title: Text(
        '\"Abc\" Wants to Use \"xyz.com\" to Sign In',
      ),
      content: Text(
        'This allows the app and website to share information about you.',
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        CupertinoDialogAction(
          child: Text('Cancel'),
          onPressed: () {
            // Drop the dialog
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        CupertinoDialogAction(
          child: Text('Continue'),
          onPressed: () {
            // Drop the dialog
            Navigator.pop(context);
            // handle continue press

          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Have you set any theme data? The widget might be pulling from your colors etc.

Comment: No, I haven't. I tried to show this in a fresh flutter project and the result was the same. Updated the code. @BenediktJSchlegel

Comment: Gonna test how it looks for me. Are you running on Android or IOS?

Comment: I am running on iOS. Thanks.

Comment: @AyushShekhar Did you find any solution yet?

Comment: @Darshana no, no solution

Answer (score 0):

I tested your Code. I get the same result.

After some digging I found this : https://issue.life/questions/57676581

Looks like the backgroundColor is hardcoded. Not sure why that would be, or why it looks different to how it should.

I also found this: [Flutter change dialog background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53683429/flutter-change-dialog-background-color) But I couldn't make any of those answers work in this case. Maybe you can though.

If nothing else works, you'll have to write your own Dialog widget. Good luck!